# Configure guard-minitest load paths?

Tags: ruby, tdd, rake, guard

I usually run my test suite with `Rake`:

**Rakefile**:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

namespace :spec do
  desc "Run all specs"
  task all: [:units]

  desc "Run all unit specs"
  Rake::TestTask.new :units do |t|
    t.pattern = "spec/unit/**/*_spec.rb"
    t.libs = ['app', 'spec']
  end
end
```

The rake task above works wonderfully. Now I wish to run it with `guard-minitest`:

**Guardfile**:

```
guard 'minitest' do
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$}) { |m| "spec/app/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^spec/(.+)\.rb$}) { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}.rb" }
end
```

However, doing this results in my load paths not being set:

```
/vagrant/spec/unit/helper.rb:5:in `require': cannot load such file -- repository (LoadError)
```

... because I'm requiring my files likes `require 'repository'` instead of `require './app/repository'`.

How can I configure [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) to use the load paths I need, like I do in my rake task?

Answer (score 2):

You could add the `app` directory to your `LOAD_PATH` directly in your `test/test_helper.rb` (or `spec/spec_helper.rb`) like:

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'app')))
```

guard-minitest adds your test helpers to minitest, even when running over drb.